# how to access $store state in js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to access vuex states, but it returns a **null**.

this is **resize.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from '../store'

console.log(store.getters.getBrowserSize.width)
```

and I imported this is main.js file

this is **store.js**:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        browser: {
            width: null,
            height: null,
            breakPoint: ''
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setBrowserSize(state, payload) {
            [state.browser.width, state.browser.height, state.browser.breakPoint] = [payload.width, payload.height, payload.breakPoint];
        }
    },
    actions: {},
    getters: {
        getBrowserSize(state) {
            return state.browser;
        }
    }
})
```

everything in store.js is fine and works (I checked theme in vue-dev-tools)

and this is **App.vue**:
here i get browser width and height, and i set theme in state.

```
data() {
            return {
                browser: {
                    width: null,
                    height: null,
                    breakPoint: ''
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            currentBreakPoint() {
                let width = window.innerWidth;
                if (width >= process.env.SIZE_XL[1]) {
                    this.browser.breakPoint = process.env.SIZE_XL[0];
                } else if (width <= process.env.SIZE_XL[1] && width >= process.env.SIZE_LG[1]) {
                    this.browser.breakPoint = process.env.SIZE_LG[0]
                } else if (width <= process.env.SIZE_LG[1] && width >= process.env.SIZE_MD[1]) {
                    this.browser.breakPoint = process.env.SIZE_MD[0]
                } else if (width <= process.env.SIZE_SM[1]) {
                    this.browser.breakPoint = process.env.SIZE_SM[0]
                }
            },
            browserSize(width, height) {
                [this.browser.width, this.browser.height] = [width, height];
                this.$store.commit("setBrowserSize", this.browser);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.currentBreakPoint();
            this.browserSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
                this.currentBreakPoint();
                this.browserSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            });
        },
```

and for [.env](https://github.com/edus44/vue-cli-plugin-env) i installed plugin and i used env variable in **vue.config.js**, and everything there works fine.

i think the whole problem is caused when i want to get state value in js file (not vue component).

whats wrong with that?

**vue.config.js** for env:

```
module.exports = {
    pluginOptions:{
        env: {
            SIZE_XL: ['xl', 1280],
            SIZE_LG: ['lg', 1024],
            SIZE_MD: ['md', 768],
            SIZE_SM: ['sm', 640]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i wonder what do you expect it to be? you instantiate it as null.

Comment: @Estradiaz it should return browser width that i didn't put the code here

Comment: Can you include the code where you set the state?

Comment: @KMLong   question updated

Comment: @Estradiaz question updated

Comment: i think you have some timing issue, as per your code `null` should be the expected output in `console.log`. I made a sandbox to toy with your issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ozob1

Comment: @Estradiaz whats wrong with my code?

i didn't understand

Comment: first you console.log your instance - not mutated and therefore `null`, then you mutate - if you access your store instance now it will have expected value - the code is not wrong btw - timing and expectations are ^^